# Renaming Files with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, rename

Here's what I need to do. I have these two columns in an excel sheet. With file names. First column has the current filename and the second column has the names I want the files to be renamed to. I need to use this as there's no pattern in renaming. For example, the below may be a set of files ...

```
Current Name >  Rename To
---------------------------
Abc.jpg       >   Dinner.jpg

Xyz.jpg       >  Driving.jpg

123.jpg       >  Sunset.jpg
```

I know it should be easy to do this in VBA, but not exactly sure how. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I think you could do something like this, using the `Name` function to rename the files, however, you will probably need to make sure the 2 columns have the complete file path, i.e. "C:\Temp\ABC.jpg"

```
Dim Source As Range
Dim OldFile As String
Dim NewFile As String

Set Source = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

For Row = 1 To Source.Rows.Count
    OldFile = ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 1)
    NewFile = ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 2)

    ' rename files
    Name OldFile As Newfile

Next
```

Comment: +1. May be worth adding a check for blank and duplicate file names