# Rename multiple pictures in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have usually been able to find an answer to my query without asking a question and I wanted to say thank you to everyone for that.  But I do have a question that I'm hoping someone can help with.

Is there a way to rename pictures in a folder where the image names are reflected in "Column A" for each image in the folder, to a new name that would be reflected in "Column B". For instance, if cell A2 contained the original image file name "Picasso1.jpg" and cell B2 contained the new image file name desired "12T.jpg" would it be possible to search through the folder find "Picasso1.jpg" and rename it "12T.jpg" I need to do this for over 3000 images on a weekly basis.  Is there a way to loop through the the spreadsheet finding each image file in the folder and renaming it its new name reflected in Column A.

Comment: Here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7508685/2258  I thought this one was a bit more direct to your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renaming Files with Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508605/renaming-files-with-excel-vba)

Comment: I removed the link I had posted. The one @RichardMorgan and user704808 posted is much better.