# Renaming multiple books

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, rename

There is book1 where in one column are the names of old books , and in another the names of new ones (old ones need to be renamed in new ones)
An error occurs : Run-time error ‘54’ File not found in line (the first one)

```
    Name OldName As NewName
```

Code :

```
   Sub Êë()

    Dim OldName, NewName
    Dim book1 As Workbook
    Dim t As Long, m As Long, n As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Ïðîåêò ñòàâêè\Ïîèñê ðåøåíèÿ\Óñîâ 
            7\âñïîìîãàòåëüíûå ïðîãðàììû\Êíèãà â ëèñò\âèç.xlsx")
    For t = 3 To 5
      book1.Worksheets("îáù").Range("C" & t).Value = n
      book1.Worksheets("îáù").Range("C" & t).Offset(0, 1).Value = m

    OldName = "n": NewName = "m"

    Name OldName As NewName
    OldName = "E:\Super M\Ïðîåêò ñòàâêè\Ïîèñê ðåøåíèÿ\Óñîâ 7\âñïîìîãàòåëüíûå 
         ïðîãðàììû\Êíèãà â ëèñò\Îòáîðíûå óñëîâèÿ\Îòêóäà\n": NewName = 
          "E:\Super M\Ïðîåêò ñòàâêè\Ïîèñê ðåøåíèÿ\Óñîâ 7\âñïîìîãàòåëüíûå 
         ïðîãðàììû\Êíèãà â ëèñò\Îòáîðíûå óñëîâèÿ\Êóäà\m"
    Name OldName As NewName

    Next t
    book1.Close

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: You're trying to rename a file from `n` to `m`. If you don't have a file named `n` in your current path, the `Name` statement will fail.

Comment: This post seems pretty similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508605/renaming-files-with-excel-vba

Comment: @PGCodeRider , i tried this code but Run-time error '75' pops up

Comment: I have complete path of file in both columns , so dont understand why