# Replace a value in a file name with an other value from an excel sheet

Tags: excel, file-rename

**Hallo I'm an IT student, and this is my first post here on stackoverflow.**

The reason I choose to create a post is because I have run into a little problem with a bulk renameing task
I have a two list of values in an excel sheet (around 25.000 rows)

I also have around 25.000 jpg files that contains the value from row 1 in their name ex:

jpg files example:

- ROS_15100.jpg
- ROS_15100_1.jpg
- ROS_15150.jpg
- ROS_18730_18731_18732_18733_25343_25043_20709_01.jpg

---

- Excel colon A1: 15100
- Excel colon A2: 15150
- Excel colon A3: 18730
- Excel colon B1: 4543455460006
- Excel colon B2: 4943691000545
- Excel colon B3: 4943691000645

I need the jpg files name to exchange the value from colon A with the value from colon B.
Any suggestions on how to do this would be very appreciated.

I tryed playing around with Bulk Rename Utility in combination with a Visiual Basic script:

```
Sub RenameFiles()
Dim xDir As String Dim xFile As String Dim xRow As Long With 
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False If .Show = -1 Then
    xDir = .SelectedItems(1)
    xFile = Dir(xDir & Application.PathSeparator & "*")
    Do Until xFile = ""
        xRow = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        xRow = Application.Match(xFile, Range("A:A"), 0)
        If xRow > 0 Then
            Name xDir & Application.PathSeparator & xFile As _
            xDir & Application.PathSeparator & Cells(xRow, "B").Value
        End If
        xFile = Dir
    Loop 
End If 
End With 
End Sub
```

But because some of the jpg files have the same number with a _1 _2 and so on this didn't quite work out the way I hoped. I have tried searching on various search engines for a solution but cant seem to find any thing, so I decided to ask the smart people in the `stackoverflow` community.

Comment: Hi. Have you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508605/renaming-files-with-excel-vba)?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a combination between `shell` and `excel-formula`.

***Excel Sheet***

**First**, run this code on column `C`.

```
=Concatenate ("ren ", A2, ".jpg", " ", B2, ".jpg")
```

*Then, drag this formula starts from `C2` to `Cn`*

**Second**,

***Shell work***

- `copy` the whole column.
- Go to the **images file**, then `create-plain-text`.
- Open it, and `paste` our values into the plain-text.
- Save the file as `.bat`.
- Run it, you will find all the images' names has been renamed.

***Enjoy!***